# Get url download from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

i develop an apps where student can upload an audio into the system. But the audio uploaded need to display at the teacher side. My problem is, how i can get the url from the uploaded audio, so that the teacher can download the audio from the student. what should i do so that the teacher can download the url?

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getAudioFile() async {
Map<String, dynamic> audios = {
  "audio": audio,
};

var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Audio");
QuerySnapshot query = await docRef.limit(10).get();
// if(query.size() > 0) {
//   query.forEach((doc) async {
//   http.Response downloadData = await http.get(doc.url);
// });
// }
return query.docs;
```

}

```
Future<String> urlDownload(file) async {
Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("files/");
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

final Future<String> downloadUrl = ref.getDownloadURL();
final http.Response downloadData = await http.get(downloadUrl);

return downloadUrl;
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after uploading file, get the url for that uploaded file

```
final url = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("files/").child('filename').getDownloadURL();
```

after that you need to store that url on database/firestore,
now both teacher and student can access it via the stored url

Comment: Is the download url can be access in 2 diff class? because i already store the url in the firestore. i just dont know how to get the url download and download the audio to the phone.

Comment: you need to store some other info with  url like , audio name, student name, etc,
then fetch that record using student name/id,
you can access that data with different classes as long as you are querying right data to firestore,

Comment: i also have similar kind of project where student upload video to firestore and it get listed in app, and bother student and teacher can see it,
check it out
https://github.com/dipakp2726/educa

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct way of doing it as of July 15, 2021

```dart
final task = storageRef.lecturesStorage('fileTitle').putFile(file));

    task.then((res) async {
      // now you got the download url correctly 
      final downloadUrl = await res.ref.getDownloadURL();
      // do something with it like putting it into a document
     }
```